# Why is *declaration* of data and functions necessary in C language, when the definition is written at the end of the source code?

Tags: c, language-design, functions, variables, declarations

Consider the following "C" code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{   
  printf("func:%d",Func_i());   
}

Func_i()
{
  int i=3;
  return i;
}
```

`Func_i()` is defined at the end of the source code and no declaration is provide before its use in `main()`. At the very time when the compiler sees `Func_i()` in `main()`, it comes out of the `main()` and finds out `Func_i()`. The compiler somehow finds the value returned by `Func_i()`and gives it to `printf()`. I also know that the compiler cannot find the *return type* of `Func_i()`. It, by default takes(guesses?) the *return type* of `Func_i()` to be `int`. That is if the code had `float Func_i()` then the compiler would give the error: *Conflicting types for `Func_i()`*.

From the above discussion we see that:

1. The compiler can find the value returned by `Func_i()`.

   > - If the compiler can find the value returned by `Func_i()` by coming out of the `main()` and searching down the source code, then why can't it find the type of Func_i(), which is *explicitly* mentioned.
2. The compiler must know that `Func_i()` is of type float--that's why it gives the error of conflicting types.

> - If the compiler knows that `Func_i` is of type float, then why does it still assume `Func_i()` to be of type int, and gives the error of conflicting types? Why don't it forcefully make `Func_i()` to be of type float.

I've the same doubt with the *variable declaration*. Consider the following "C" code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  /* [extern int Data_i;]--omitted the declaration */
  printf("func:%d and Var:%d",Func_i(),Data_i);
}

 Func_i()
{
  int i=3;
  return i;
}
int Data_i=4;
```

The compiler gives the error: *'Data_i' undeclared(first use in this function).*

> - When the compiler sees `Func_i()`, it goes down to the source code to find the value returned by Func_(). Why can't the compiler do the same for the variable Data_i?

**Edit:**

I don't know the details of the inner working of compiler, assembler, processor etc. The basic idea of my question is that if I tell(write) the return-value of the function in the source code at last, after the use of that function then the "C" language allows the computer to find that value without giving any error. Now why can't the computer find the type similarly. Why can't the type of Data_i be found as Func_i()'s return value was found. Even if I use the `extern data-type identifier;` statement, I am not telling the value to be returned by that identifier(function/variable). If the computer can find that value then why can't it find the type. Why do we need the forward declaration at all?

Thank you.

Comment: The compiler doesn't "find" the value returned by Func_i. this is done at execution time.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod The execution is done line-by-line. The only way to find the value returned by `Func_i()` is to jump out of the main--Even if this happens at the runtime; the question is still valid. If this is done at execution time then what does happen at the compilation time? To what is the `Func_i()` translated?

Comment: Why the downvote? I put all my efforts to write a clear and to-the-point question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is based on some serious misunderstandings of how compilers work, and your responses in comments suggest you still have some conceptual hurdles to overcome.

Comment: The purpose of this question is to overcome those hurdles.

Comment: Absolutely, but you should use the comments and answers to make yourself rethink your assumptions about how things work.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod:  What you're suggesting is that the questioner go find the answer elsewhere before asking the question.

Comment: No, just that the OP not question the responses as if they might be incorrect rather than his or her understanding being a little off.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Are header files actually good?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180904/are-header-files-actually-good) "Original purpose of header files was to allow single-pass compilation and modularity in C. By declaring the methods before they are used, it allowed for only single compilation pass..."

Comment: Note that the first sample code has not been valid, standard-conforming code for the last fifteen years; C99 made the absence of a return type in the function definitions and the implicit declaration of `Func_i` invalid.  There never was a rule to implicitly declare undefined variables, so the second fragment was always malformed.  (Yes, compilers do accept the first sample still because it was valid, if sloppy, under C89/C90.)

Comment: The compiler assumes the return type is `int`. If later, it discovers it is not `int`, it will report an error.

Comment: @user31782: Bottom line to the question: **Why does language X do/require Y?** _Because that is the choice the designers made._ You seem to be are arguing that the designers of the one of the most successful languages ever should have made different choices decades ago rather than trying to understand those choices in the context they were made. The answer to your question: **Why do we need forward declaration?** has been given: _Because C uses a one-pass compiler._ The simplest answer to most of your follow up questions is _Because then it wouldn't be a one-pass compiler._

Comment: @Mr.Mindor I ain't sayin' that *the designers of the one of the most successful languages ever **should have made different choices***. I'm asking _why the designers of the one of the most successful languages made these choices_?--would making other choices cause the programs translated from their language to become slow or something. If a _one-pass_ compiler can know the _return-value_ then it should also be able to know the _return-type_.

Comment: @user31782 You really, really want to read the [dragon's book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) to get an understanding of how compilers and processors actually work - it's just impossible to distill all the required knowledge into a single SO answer (or even 100 at that). Great book for anyone with an interest in compilers.

Comment: @user31782. YES, different choices would have had different results. C has been successful largely because of its efficiency, Any scheme allowing for run-time identification of type would have killed that efficiency. It would require _always_ returning an extra value holding the type identifier, evaluation of the type identifier and emitting dozens of extra instructions that ultimately would never be executed. As others have stated, the compiler does **not** know the _return-value_. Unless the _return-value_ is a constant it never _really_ knows the _return-value_.

Comment: Remember that C was originally written on the [PDP-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11), and that was a [16-bit minicomputer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture#Interrupts) that came with a limit of 64 KiB for the code and another 64 KiB for the data (on the bigger versions with split code and data spaces; for the smaller versions, it was 64 KiB code plus data) and didn't reach 1 Mips.  This limited what was possible in ways which people used to multiple GiB of memory have difficulty understanding.

Comment: I would downvote if I had enough reputation.

Comment: @KorayTugay Why would you downvote?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because C is a **single-pass**, **statically-typed**, **weakly-typed**, **compiled** language.

1. **Single-pass** means the compiler does not look ahead to see the definition of a function or variable. Since the compiler does not look ahead, the declaration of a function must come before the use of the function, otherwise the compiler does not know what its type signature is. However, the definition of the function can be later on in the same file, or even in a different file altogether. See point #4.

   The only exception is the historical artifact that undeclared functions and variables are presumed to be of type "int". Modern practice is to avoid implicit typing by always declaring functions and variables explicitly.
2. **Statically-typed** means that all type information is computed at compile time. That information is then used to generate machine code that executes at run time. There is no concept in C of run-time typing. Once an int, always an int, once a float, always a float. However, that fact is somewhat obscured by the next point.
3. **Weakly-typed** means that the C compiler automatically generates code to convert between numeric types without requiring the programmer to explicitly specify the conversion operations. Because of static typing, the same conversion will always be carried out in the same way each time through the program. If a float value is converted to an int value at a given spot in the code, a float value will always be converted to an int value at that spot in the code. This cannot be changed at run-time. The value itself may change from one execution of the program to the next, of course, and conditional statements may change which sections of code are run in what order, but a given single section of code without function calls or conditionals will always perform the exact same operations whenever it is run.
4. **Compiled** means that the process of analyzing the human-readable source code and transforming it into machine-readable instructions is fully carried out before the program runs. When the compiler is compiling a function, it has no knowledge of what it will encounter further down in a given source file. However, once compilation (and assembly, linking, etc) have completed, each function in the finished executable contains numeric pointers to the functions that it will call when it is run. That is why main() can call a function further down in the source file. By the time main() is actually run, it will contain a pointer to the address of Func_i().

   Machine code is very, very specific. The code for adding two integers (3 + 2) is different from the one for adding two floats (3.0 + 2.0). Those are both different from adding an int to a float (3 + 2.0), and so on. The compiler determines for every point in a function what exact operation needs to be carried out at that point, and generates code that carries out that exact operation. Once that has been done, it cannot be changed without recompiling the function.

Putting all these concepts together, the reason that main() cannot "see" further down to determine the type of Func_i() is that type analysis occurs at the very beginning of the compilation process. At that point, only the part of the source file up to the definition of main() has been read and analyzed, and the definition of Func_i() is not yet known to the compiler.

The reason that main() can "see" where Func_i() is to **call** it is that calling happens at run time, after compilation has already resolved all of the names and types of all of the identifiers, assembly has already converted all of the functions to machine code, and linking has already inserted the correct address of each function in each place it is called.

I have, of course, left out most of the gory details. The actual process is much, much more complicated. I hope that I have provided enough of a high-level overview to answer your questions.

Additionally, please remember, what I have written above specifically applies to C.

In other languages, the compiler may make multiple passes through the source code, and so the compiler could pick up the definition of Func_i() without it being predeclared.

In other languages, functions and / or variables may be dynamically typed, so a single variable could hold, or a single function could be passed or return, an integer, a float, a string, an array, or an object at different times.

In other languages, typing may be stronger, requiring conversion from floating-point to integer to be explicitly specified. In yet other languages, typing may be weaker, allowing conversion from the string "3.0" to the float 3.0 to the integer 3 to be carried out automatically.

And in other languages, code may be interpreted one line at a time, or compiled to byte-code and then interpreted, or just-in-time compiled, or put through a wide variety of other execution schemes.

Comment: Thank you for an all-in-one answer. Your and nikie's answer is what I wanted to know. E.g. `Func_()+1`: here at the compilation time the compiler _has_ to know the type of `Func_i()` so as to generate the appropriate machine code. Perhaps either it is not _possible_ for the assembly to handle `Func_()+1` by calling the type at run time, or it is possible but doing so will make the program slow at the run-time. I think, its enough for me for now.

Comment: Important detail of C's implicitly declared functions: They are assumed to be of type `int func(...)` ... i.e. they take a variadic argument list. This means if you define a function as `int putc(char)` but forget to declare it, it will instead be called as `int putc(int)` (because char passed through a variadic argument list is promoted to `int`). So while the OP's example happened to work because its signature matched the implicit declaration, it's understandable why this behavior was discouraged (and appropriate warnings added).

Answer (score 42):

A design constraint of the C language was that it was supposed to be compiled by a single-pass compiler, which makes it suitable for very memory-constrained systems. Therefore, the compiler knows at any point only about stuff that was mentioned before. The compiler can't skip forward in the source to find a function declaration and then go back to compile a call to that function. Therefore, all symbols ought to be declared before they are used. You can pre-declare a function like

```
int Func_i();
```

at the top or in a header file to help the compiler.

In your examples, you use two dubious features of the C language that should be avoided:

1. If a function is used before it was properly declared, this is used as an “implicit declaration”. The compiler uses the immediate context to figure out the function signature. The compiler will not scan through the rest of the code to figure out what the real declaration is.
2. If something is declared without a type, the type is taken to be `int`. This is e.g. the case for static variables or function return types.

So in `printf("func:%d",Func_i())`, we have an implicit declaration `int Func_i()`. When the compiler reaches the function definition `Func_i() { ... }`, this is compatible with the type. But if you wrote `float Func_i() { ... }` at this point, you have the implicity declared `int Func_i()` and the explicitly declared `float Func_i()`. Since the two declarations don't match, the compiler gives you an error.

#### Clearing up some misconceptions

- The compiler does not find the value returned by `Func_i`. The absence of an explicit type means that the return type is `int` by default. Even if you do this:

  ```
  Func_i() {
      float f = 42.3;
      return f;
  }
  ```

  then the type will be `int Func_i()`, and the return value will be silently truncated!
- The compiler eventually gets to know the real type of `Func_i`, but it does not know the real type during the implicit declaration. Only when it later reaches the real declaration can it find out whether the implicitly declared type was correct. But at that point, the assembly for the function call might already have been written and can't be changed in the C compilation model.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't jump down to find the returned value of `Func_i()`, then how does it print that value. Suppose I put a getchar() after the printf(). Now the processing will have to stop until I press something. There is now no way for the computer to go down to find the returned value but it somehow still prints the correct value.

Comment: @user31782:  The order of the code matters at compile time, but not at run time.  The compiler is out of the picture when the program runs.  By run time, the function will have been assembled and linked, its address will have been resolved and stuck into the call's address placeholder.  (It's a little more complex than that, but that's the basic idea.)  The processor can branch forward or backward.

Comment: @Blrfl Can the same be happen to Data_i(). That is the processor jump to the memory location where Data_i()'s value is stored.

Comment: @user31782: The compiler _doesn't_ print the value. Your compiler doesn't run the program!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know that. I mistakenly wrote _compiler_ in my comment above because I forgot the name _processor_.

Comment: You say: _"The compiler does not find the value returned by Func_i"_ Then how is the value of `Func_i()` get printed? Could you explain in simple language. If the return-value of `Func_i()` can be known at the run-time then can't the same mechanism be used to find the _type_ of `Func_i()` and `Data_i`, when no forward declaration is provided for both?

Comment: @user31782 This is possible, and some languages do that. C is not one of those languages. With predeclarations, the compiler can go through the file almost line by line and can immediately print out assembly code for that line with all the information currently known. Without predeclarations, the whole file would have to be loaded into memory, and type analysis becomes more complicated. The compiler turns the text of the source file into binary codes, where a function is just a sequence of codes that starts at a *known position*. A function call is a jump to this position – no need to search.

Comment: Why don't the processor jump to the point where the information of the _type_ of the function is mentioned? If the processor can jump to find the _return value_ then why not jump to find the _return type_?

Comment: @user31782 The job of the compiler is to create a binary file where we can jump efficiently to known locations. But the source code is a text file. When we see a function name `Func_i`, where do we jump to? Line 12? Line 10123? The compiler doesn't know, so the whole file would have to be loaded into memory at once and the compiler would have to search through everything. (Actually, knowing the line number wouldn't even be enough – computers operate on bytes and it would be even more difficult to find the exact byte where a function definition starts).

Comment: Then how does it know at which line the _return-value_ is mentioned?

Comment: Why is the default type an int? That seems kind of off. I'd think Unit would be a better assumed type.

Comment: @Carcigenicate C was heavily influenced by the B language, which only had a single type: an word-width integral numeric type that could also be used for pointers. C originally copied this behaviour, but it's now completely outlawed since the C99 standard. `Unit` makes a nice default type from a type-theory viewpoint, but fails in the practicalities of the close to the metal systems programming that B and then C were designed for.

Comment: @user31782: The compiler must know the type of the variable in order to generate the correct assembly for the processor. When the compiler finds the implicit `Func_i()`, it _immediately_ generates and saves code for the processor to jump to another location, then to receive some integer, and then continue.  When the compiler later finds the `Func_i` definition, it makes sure the signatures match, and if they do, it places the assembly for `Func_i()` at that address, and tells it to return some integer.  When you run the program, the processor then follows those instructions with the value `3`.

Answer (score 11):

First, you programs are valid for the C90 standard, but not for those following. implicit int (allowing to declare a function without giving its return type), and implicit declaration of functions (allowing to use a function without declaring it) are no more valid.

Second, that doesn't work as you think.

1. Result type are optional in C90, not giving one means an `int` result.  That it is also true for variable declaration (but you have to give a storage class, `static` or `extern`).
2. What the compiler does when seeing the `Func_i` is called without a previous declaration, is assuming that there is a declaration

   ```
   extern int Func_i();
   ```

   it doesn't look further in the code to see how effectively `Func_i` is declared.  If `Func_i` wasn't declared or defined, the compiler would not change its behavior when compiling `main`.  The implicit declaration is only for function, there is none for variable.

   Note that the empty parameter list in the declaration doesn't mean the function doesn't take parameters (you need to specify `(void)` for that), it does mean that the compiler doesn't have to check the types of the parameters and will the same implicit conversions that are applied to arguments passed to variadic functions.

Comment: If the compiler can find the value returned by Func_i() by coming out of the main() and searching down the source code, then why can't it find the type of Func_i(), which is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @user31782  If there was no previous declaration of Func_i, when seeing that Func_i is used in a call expression, behaves as if there was one `extern int Func_i()`. It doesn't look anywhere.

Comment: When the compiler sees `extern int Func_i()`, does it then jump down to find the value returned by `Func_i()`?

Comment: @user31782, the compiler doesn't jump anywhere.  It will emit code to call that function; the value returned will be determined at run-time.  Well, in the case of such a simple function which is present in the same compilation unit, the optimization phase may inline the function, but that's not something you should think about when considering the rules of the language, it is an optimization.

Comment: How is the return-value found at run time. Does the compiler replace the function-call by its definition?

Comment: @user31782, you have serious misunderstandings about how programs work.  So serious that I don't think p.se is a good place to correct them (perhaps the chat, but I won't try to do it).

Comment: @user31782: Writing a small snippet and compiling it with `-S` (if you are using `gcc`) will allow you to look at the assembly code generated by the compiler. Then you can have an idea of how return-values are handled at run-time (normally using a processor register, or some space on the program stack).

Answer (score 7):

You wrote in a comment:

> The execution is done line-by-line. The only way to find the value returned by Func_i() is to jump out of the main

That's a misconception: Execution isn't don line-by-line. *Compilation* is done line by line, and name resolution is done during compilation, and it only resolves names, not return values.

A helpful conceptual model is this: When the compiler reads the line:

```
  printf("func:%d",Func_i());
```

it emits code equivalent to:

```
  1. call "function #2" and put the return value on the stack
  2. put the constant string "func:%d" on the stack
  3. call "function #1"
```

The compiler also makes a note in some internal table that `function #2` is a not yet declared function named `Func_i`, that takes an unspecified number of arguments and returns an int (the default).

Later, when it parses this:

```
 int Func_i() { ...
```

the compiler looks up `Func_i` in the table mentioned above and checks if the parameters and the return type match. If they don't, it stops with an error message. If they do, it adds the current address to the internal function table and goes on to the next line.

So, the compiler didn't "look" for `Func_i` when it parsed the first reference. It simply made a note in some table, the went on parsing the next line. And at the end of the file, it has an object file, and a list of jump addresses.

Later, the linker takes all this, and replaces all pointers to "function #2" with the actual jump address, so it emits something like:

```
  call 0x0001215 and put the result on the stack
  put constant ... on the stack
  call ...
...
[at offset 0x0001215 in the file, compiled result of Func_i]:
  put 3 on the stack
  return top of the stack
```

Much later, when the executable file is run, the jump address is already resolved, and the computer can just jump to address 0x1215. No name lookup required.

*Disclaimer*: As I said, that's a conceptual model, and the real world is more complicated. Compilers and linkers do all kinds of crazy optimizations today. They even *might* "jump up an down" to look for `Func_i`, although I doubt it. But the C languages is defined in a way that you *could* write a super-simple compiler like that. So most of the time, it's a very useful model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can't the compiler emit the code: `1.  call "function #2", put the return-type onto the stack and put the return value on the stack?`

Comment: One small correction: `Func_i` takes an unspecified number of arguments (0 or more).

Comment: @user31782: No, because the emitted code doesn't contain any types; There are no real types in assembly code, that's why it's so fast. And also because not all types are treated the same: For example, an x86 CPU has a separate stack for floating point numbers and "ordinary" data. And pass-by-value structures are another beast entirely.

Comment: (Cont.) Also: What if you wrote `printf(..., Func_i()+1);` -  the compiler *has* to know the type of `Func_i`, so it can decide if it should emit an `add integer` or an `add float` instruction. You might find *some* special cases where the compiler could go on without the type information, but the compiler has to work for *all* cases.

Comment: `Func()+1` should be translated to `call "function #2" and put the return value + 1 on the stack`.

Comment: The compiler should emit such kind of code which would treat the return-value of Func_i correctly. E.g. `float x;` should be translated to `reserve memory for a floating point number on stack`. Similarily for `Func_i()` we should have `reserve memory for call-"function #2"-and-put-its-type number onto stack`.

Comment: @user31782: It seems you are now suggesting the computer architecture be modified. Going down that route makes it no longer a language question...

Comment: @Mr.Mindor I'm not suggesting to modify computer architecture. I'm trying to understand why _forward declaration_ is necessary. And why can't the type be inferred as the return-value can be.

Comment: @user31782: If you write a compiler for a VM, like the java compiler, you can do all those things. But C (and C compilers) were designed to emit actual machine code, and there simply is no machine code instruction for "reserve memory for whatever type some function returns". There are instructions like "increment the stack pointer by [insert constant here]". You *could* emit code that explicitly handles different types (in C++, you can actually do stuff like that), but that would mean type checks at runtime, which costs performance - no real C programmer would want this.

Comment: What I meant is this, The compiler should emit such kind of code which would handle the return-value of Func_i correctly. E.g. `float x;` should be translated to `Handle x as a floating point number and reserve 4 bytes for it on stack`. Similarily for `Func_i()` we should have `handle Func_i() as a call-function#2-and-put-its-type number and put its value onto the stack`. This doesn't require type-check at runtime.

Comment: @user31782: Like I said, might be possible for special cases. But take `Func_i()+1`: A typical CPU has several different "add" instructions, one for 32bit-integers, one for 16-bit integers, one for 32bit floats, and so on. The compiler has to know which one to emit, so it either has to know the types of both all subexpressions, or it has to decide which one to call at runtime (which is expensive).

Comment: Can't we translate `Func_i()+1;` as: `handle Func_i() as a "call-function#2-and-put-its-type" number and put its value onto the stack _and_ add it to 1, assuming Func_i() to be a "call-function#2-and-put-its-size-in-bits" number.` Perhaps this is requiring the check of what code to be emitted at run-time as you said.

Comment: @user31782: Machine instructions, as a rule, are *very* simple: Add two 32-bit integer registers. Load a memory address to a 16-bit integer register. Jump to an address. Also, there are no *types*: You can happily load a memory location that represents a 32bit float number into a 32bit integer register and do some arithmetic with it. (It just rarely makes sense.) So no, you can't emit machine code like that directly. You could write a compiler that does all those things with runtime checks and extra type data on the stack. But it wouldn't be a C compiler.

Comment: To what is the statement `float x;` translated into assembly?

Comment: @user31782: Depends, IIRC. `float` values can live in an FPU register - then there would be no instruction at all. The compiler just keeps track which value is stored in which register during compilation, and emits stuff like "add constant 1 to FP register X". Or it could live on the stack, if there are no free registers. Then there would be "increase stack pointer by 4" instruction, and the value would be "referenced" as something like "stack pointer - 4". But all these things only work if the sizes of all variables (before and after) on the stack are known at compile-time.

Comment: From all the discussion I've reached to this understanding: For the compiler to make a plausible assembly code for any statement including `Func_i()` or/and `Data_i`, it has to determine their types; it is not possible in assembly language to make a call to the data type. I need to study things in detail myself to be assured.

Answer (score 5):

C and a number of other languages which require declarations were designed in an era when processor time and memory were expensive. The development of C and Unix went hand in hand for quite some time, and the latter didn't have virtual memory until 3BSD appeared in 1979.  Without the extra room to work, compilers tended to be [single-pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_compiler) affairs because they didn't require the ability to keep some representation of the entire file in memory all at once.

Single-pass compilers are, like us, saddled with an inability to see into the future.  This means the only things they can know for sure are what they've been told explicitly before the line of code being compiled.  It's plain to either of us that `Func_i()` is declared later in the source file, but the compiler, which operates on a small chunk of code at a time, has no clue it's coming.

In early C (AT&T, K&R, C89), use of a function `foo()` before declaration resulted in a *de facto* or implicit declaration of `int foo()`.  Your example works works when `Func_i()` is declared `int` because it matches what the compiler declared on your behalf.  Changing it to any other type will result in a conflict because it no longer matches what the compiler chose in the absence of an explicit declaration.  This behavior was removed in C99, where use of an undeclared function became an error.

So what about return types?

The calling convention for object code in most environments requires knowing only the address of the function being called, which is relatively easy for compilers and linkers to deal with.  Execution jumps to the start of the function and comes back when it returns.  Anything else, notably arrangements of passing arguments and a return value, is determined entirely by the caller and callee in an arrangement called a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).  As long as both share the same set of conventions, it becomes possible for a program to call functions in other object files whether they were compiled in any language that shares those conventions.  (In scientific computing, you run into a lot of C calling FORTRAN and vice versa, and the ability to do that comes from having a calling convention.)

One other feature of early C was that prototypes as we know them now didn't exist.  You could declare a function's return type (e.g., `int foo()`), but not its arguments (i.e., `int foo(int bar)` was not an option).  This existed because, as outlined above, the program always stuck to a calling convention that could be determined by the arguments.  If you called a function with the wrong type of arguments, it was a garbage in, garbage out situation.

Because object code has the notion of a return but not a return type, a compiler has to know the return type to deal with the value returned.  When you're running machine instructions, it's all just bits and the processor doesn't care whether the memory where you're trying to compare a `double` actually has an `int` in it.  It just does what you ask, and if you break it, you own both pieces.

Consider these bits of code:

```
double foo();         double foo();
double x;             int x;
x = foo();            x = foo();
```

The code on the left compiles down to a call to `foo()` followed by copying the result provided via the call/return convention into wherever `x` is stored.  That's the easy case.

The code on the right shows a type conversion and is why compilers need to know a function's return type.  Floating-point numbers can't be dumped into memory where other code will expect to see an `int` because there's no magic conversion that takes place.  If the end result has to be an integer, there have to be instructions that guide the processor to make the conversion before storage.  Without knowing the return type of `foo()` ahead of time, the compiler would have no idea that conversion code is necessary.

Multi-pass compilers enable all sorts of things, one of which is the ability to declare variables, functions and methods after they're first used.  This means that when the compiler gets around to compiling the code, it has already seen the future and knows what to do.  Java, for example, mandates multi-pass by virtue of the fact that its syntax allows declaration after use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer(+1). I don't know the details of the inner working of compiler, assembler, processor etc. The basic idea of my question is that if I tell(write) the return-value of the function in the source code at last, after the use of that function then the language allows the _computer_ to find that value without giving any error. Now why can't the computer find the _type_ similarly. Why can't the _type_ of Data_i be found as `Func_i()`'s return value was found.

Comment: I am still not satisfied. `double foo();  int x;  x = foo();` simply gives the error. I know that we can't do this. My question is that in the function call the processor finds the return-value only; why can't it also find the return-type too?

Comment: `double foo();  int x;  x = foo();` is not giving error.

Comment: @user31782:  It shouldn't.   There's a prototype for `foo()`, so the compiler knows what to do with it.

Comment: @user31782:  Processors don't have any notion of return type.

Comment: @user31782 For the compile time question: It is possible to write a language in which all this type analysis can be done at compile time. C is not such a language. The C compiler can't do it because it is not designed to do it. Could it have been designed differently? Sure, but it would take much more processing power and memory to do so. Bottom line is it wasn't. It was designed in a manner the computers of the day were best able to handle.

Comment: @user31782 for the run-time question: As others have stated, the processor does not 'find' the return value, it doesn't know types. A compiled program is simply a series of instructions that work on raw data stored in memory. `ADDi $1 $2 $3` (Add the int from $1 to the int from $2 and store it at $3) `JMPr $5`, `MV $6 $7`.  Any given address in memory might be an int, or it might be a float, or it might be an instruction, or a char, or... In general there is no way of looking at that memory and determining what it is.

Comment: @Blrfl What's up with `Data_i()`? Can the processor jump to find it's value like it does with `Func_i()`, when no declaration is provide before the use?

Comment: @Mr.Mindor For the compile time question: It is possible to write a language in which all this type analysis can be done at compile time. It depends on the language design. Yes it is possible in dynamic typed languages (there is no compile time type analysis needed). With compile time analysis it can get comlicated to impossible, especially with recursive functions. Example:
a(x)
{
y=doSomething(x);
return b(y);
}
b(y)
{
if(condition) return y;
z=doSomething2(y);
return b(z);
}
where doSomething and doSomething2 return other types then their parameter.

Comment: The compiler would have to emulate running to get the correct possible return types. It gets similar to the halting problem.
So it also depends on language design and what the language allows and what the compilers of that language support (some compilers might decide not to allow all parts of the language like in this example.

Comment: doSomething might be a function which makes a new container and add the parameter to the container and return the container or use the parameter as container and return it's first element.

Comment: @sweethome of course the full story is more complicated than is allowed (or in this case I felt prudent) to place in a comment.